# Required parameter is missing: grant_type ngCordova/angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, ngcordova

I am using Google oAuth along with ngCordova. While I am able to retrieve access_token, the subsequent call to get refresh_token is failing. Here is my request.
[image]

I have ensured that

1. Content type is set.
2. data is posted as form data and not in url as query string.

Here is the Javascript code

```
var clientSecret = encodeURI(result["access_token"]);
var req = {
    method: "POST",
    url:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
           },
    data : {"code":clientSecret,"client_id":"XXXXX","client_secret":"XXX",
            "redirect_uri":"","grant_type":"authorization_code",scope:""}
};
$http(req).success(...).error(...);
```

Please someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad, the problem was with the authentication approach chosen by me. I was using ngCordova to invoke google authentication flow, which sets `response_type` to `token`. In my case, since I was expecting `refresh token` to be created once user authorizes app, the `response_type` was supposed to be set to `code`.

I modified the code and it worked.